# Looking at other people cameras in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am working on a multiplayer game in unity and i want to add a funcion that let me see at another player's camera trough a small window [just like in the game Portal.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esWGJyONPTw&t=255s)
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way

Comment: Good, i thought there was no way

Comment: Try looking up [Render Textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) in the Unity Manual. They should provide the functionalities that you need.